# Flutter ListViews with other Items

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I've been experimenting with ListViews a little and have come across a use case that I am unsure how to create.

Say I have a list of data that I'd like to display using a `ListView.builder()` which iterates through the list and creates a card for each one. Simple, enough.

However, now I'd like to add a button at the bottom of this list that does something useful, and it must be a part of the same scroll as the listview above it.

So, I'd like a scrolling list of data with a button at the bottom.
My first thought was to simply put the listview in a column with the button but, of course, the button is not a part of the scroll in this case.

I then thought of nesting the `ListView.builder()` inside of a standard `ListView()` like so -

```
ListView(
  children: [
    ListView.builder(
      ...
    ),
    RaisedButton(...),
  ],
)
```

Unofrtunately I received errors upon trying this, but am not even sure if this is the correct solution.
Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the button as the last item of the `ListView.builder`

```
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 10,//Add One more for the button
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    // If it is the last item return the button
    if (index == 9) {
      return RaisedButton(onPressed: null);
    }

    //If not, return a card
    return Card();
  },
);
```

Comment: Ahhg that fits the bill, thank you! Although, to me at least, it seems like a bit of a botch. I just wonder if there's some slightly cleaner implementation.